# formatting epigrams using csquotes

Tags: csquotes

In the book that I am writing I occasionally begin a chapter or section with an epigram. Given that I am using the `csquotes` package, is there a way that when I invoke `\blockquote` at the beginning of a section or chapter that the formatting automatically universally uses a pre-defined setting (tabbed to the right side of the page and justified)?

Comment: i don't know whether `csquotes` has the positioning facility you mention, but there is a very nice package `epigraph` (`texdoc epigraph`) that you might want to take a look at.

Comment: I was also going to recommend `epigraph`. I've always used that for these kinds of cases and it works well, is flexible and pretty straightforward.

Comment: epigraph looks like a good option. what is the easiest way to get a footnote citation of the author which appears at the bottom of the page? When I use `\autocite`, it becomes a mini-footnote below the epigrapm.

Comment: regarding a footnote, i'd try `\footnotemark` on the author, and `\footnotetext` separately outside the epigraph.  it may be necessary to fiddle with the assignment of the mark itself, if that by default is a symbol or letter rather than the usual number -- but i haven't tried it, so can't offer better advice just now.

Comment: I did as you mentioned `\footnotemark` after the author, and outside `\footnotetext` along with `\fullcite`. Its a bit long, but does the trick.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you want to write an answer?